# Issue occurs while build apk in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

This kind of error occurs, dom 25.12.0 not present on that location, and annotation did not change after changing its version.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

```
 1: Task failed with an exception.
 -----------
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseRFile'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
 > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
   - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/firebase/firebase- 
  bom/25.12.0/firebase-bom-25.12.0.pom
   - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/firebase/firebase- 
  bom/25.12.0/firebase-bom-25.12.0.jar
 Required by:
     project :
 > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
 Required by:
     project :
 > Could not find androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
   Searched in the following locations:
   - 
 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation- 
 1.1.0.pom
   - 
 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation- 
 1.1.0.jar
 Required by:
     project :

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
  log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
   ==============================================================================

   2: Task failed with an exception.
   -----------
  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':javaPreCompileRelease'.
  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0.
 Required by:
     project :
  > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
    Required by:
     project :
  > Could not find androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
   Required by:
     project :

 * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
 log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 11s


  The plugin firebase_core could not be built due to the issue above.
```

my pubspec.yml file:-

```
                name: Dreamcart
         description: A new Flutter application.


          version: 2.1.0

         environment:
          sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

       dependencies:
      flutter:
      sdk: flutter
      flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
    cached_network_image: 2.2.0
    fluttertoast: ^6.0.1
    flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.0
    flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
    mvc_pattern: ^3.4.1
    global_configuration: ^1.3.0
    http: ^0.12.0+2
    intl: any
    html: ^0.14.0+2
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
    flutter_html: ^0.10.4
    flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
    location: ^2.3.5
    dynamic_theme: ^1.0.0
    flutter_inappbrowser: ^1.2.2
    url_launcher: ^5.4.1
    firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
    firebase_analytics: ^4.0.2
    razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.1
    otp_screen: ^0.0.3
    marquee: ^1.7.0
    keyboard_actions: ^1.0.4
    keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
    flutter_typeahead: ^2.0.0
    carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
    speech_recognition: ^0.3.0+1
    permission_handler: ^4.2.0
    firebase_core: ^0.5.0


  dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter


  flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/img/Dreamcartlogo.png"
  android: "launcher_icon"

  flutter:


  assets:
   - assets/cfg/
   - assets/img/
   - assets/img/visa.png
   - assets/img/paypal.png
   - assets/img/paypal2.png
   - assets/img/apple_pay.png
   - assets/img/brazil.png
   - assets/img/canada.png
   - assets/img/china.png
   - assets/img/france.png
   - assets/img/germany.png
   - assets/img/italy.png
   - assets/img/netherlands.png
   - assets/img/spain.png
   - assets/img/united-arab-emirates.png
   - assets/img/united-states-of-america.png
   - assets/img/marker.png
   - assets/img/my_marker.png
   - assets/img/mastercard.png
   - assets/img/visacard.png
   - assets/img/wallet.png
   - assets/img/cash.png
   - assets/img/pay_pickup.png
   - assets/img/logo.png
   - assets/img/loading.gif
   - assets/img/loading_card.gif
   - assets/img/loading_trend.gif

# An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
# https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

# For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
# https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

# To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
# in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
# "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
# list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
# example:
  fonts:
  - family: Poppins
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf
      weight: 100
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf
      weight: 200
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
      weight: 300
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
      weight: 400
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
      weight: 500
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
      weight: 600
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf
      weight: 800
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf
      weight: 900
```

app/build.gradle file :-

```
         def localProperties = new Properties()
       def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
      if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
       localProperties.load(reader)
     }
    }

   def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
     local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '9'
  }

   def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
 if (flutterVersionName == null) {
     flutterVersionName = '2.1.0'
   }

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

  def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
  def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
  keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 30

   lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
 }

  defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
 (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.portalperfect.dreamcart"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
 }

   signingConfigs {
     release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

     buildTypes {
     release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
         minifyEnabled true
         useProguard true
         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         }
    }
   }

     flutter {
      source '../..'
  }

  configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
      force 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
  }
 }

 dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1"
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle :-

```
                   buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   }
  }

   allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
       center()
      }
     }

  rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
       project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
  subprojects {
     project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
   }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

I tried so much but no solutions found for this issue. Help me out. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mention the version of firebase plugins or use updated version